# app.config using linq to sql issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, c#-3.0, app-config

In a C# 2008 application, I used linq to SQL to connect to a SQL server 2008  database. Now I want to obtain the connection of the database from the app.config file instead of hardcoding the value into the application. I want to be able to change the connection string to the database since I  will be moving this application from unit testing database to user acceptance database to the the prodction database.

Right now I am getting the error message, ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I know this error message is coming from the line of code that I listed below since it is the only line of code I changed.

The following is a snippet of the code from the *.designer.cs file (this is part of the dbml file).

```
using System.Configuration;

public esampleDataContext() : 
 base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sample.Properties.Settings.DEVConnectionString"].ConnectionString,mappingSource)
```

**Note: `base(global::sample.Properties.Settings.Default.DEVConnectionString, mappingSource)` is the line of code that I replaced that was generated by the .NET framework

I want to mention the following:

1. The *.dbml file is associated with a particular project file.
2. The connection string settings for this *.dbml file are the following:

   1. DEVConnectionString (settings)
   2. Connection String = Data Source=dev1;Initial Catalog=DEV_test;Integrated Security=True
   3. application settings=True
   4. settings property name is DEVConnectionString.
3. The project file that has the *.dbml file. has a reference set to the system.configuration.

**Note: This code in similar applications that I wrote, but I do not why it does not work here.

Thus can you tell me, show me in code, and/or point me to a reference that I can use so I can obtain the value in the app.config file for the database connection string I want to use. I do not want to use a hard-coded connection string to the database.

Comment: Is your connection string in the app.config called `sample.Properties.Settings.DEVConnectionString`? If not, that'll be why it's failing as it can't find that in the dictionary and is returning null/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If I have the app.config file set to the following, is this ok: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="sample.Properties.Settings.DEVConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=instance1\DEV;Initial Catalog=dev3;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> Is the providerName here causing some kind of a problem? Can you explain more of what you mean by "If not, that'll be why it's failing as it can't find that in the dictionary and is returning null/?" I do not totally understand what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to get the value from connection strings section in app configuration not the settings provider. just add "sample.Properties.Settings.DEVConnectionString" in your app config.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <connectionStrings>
         <add name="sample.Properties.Settings.DEVConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=dev1;Initial Catalog=DEV_test;Integrated Security=True"
    <connectionStrings>

    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```